# Getting variation SKU if the product is not simple

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have a plugin that outputs the SKU of an ordered product to CSV and it works perfectly, however whenever a variable product is ordered the sku is empty.

I've looked at the code responsible and can see its looking for product_id then outputting get_sku however putting in a conditional and changing product_id to variable_id doesn't work, here is what I have so far;

```
foreach($this->order->get_items() as $item) {
    $this->lines[] = $this->addOrderLine($item);
}

public function __construct($item, $order)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->product = wc_get_product($item->get_product_id());
    }

public function getSku()
    {
        return $this->product->get_sku();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: use `$this->product = $item->get_product();`

Comment: You're an absolute wizard @LoicTheAztec thank you so much - I'm sending over a tip as a thank you!